# Modern C++ builder pattern without unique_ptr

Tags: c++, builder

I'd want to implement a builder pattern in modern C++. Coming from Java background, this is something I'd like to emulate:

```
// Usage
FooBuilder builder;
builder.setArg1(a);
builder.setArg2(b);
Foo foo = builder.build();

// Implementation
public class FooBuilder {
    // ...
    public Foo build() {
        return new Foo(a, b);
    }
}
```

Typical older textbooks just advice one to do it like that in C++:

```
class FooBuilder {
    // ...
    Foo* build() {
        return new Foo(m_a, m_b);
    }
}
```

which is obviously not a good idea, as dealing with raw pointers might be error-prone. The best I've came up with so far is using `std::unique_ptr` manually:

```
class FooBuilder {
    // ...
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> build() {
        return std::make_unique<Foo>(m_a, m_b);
    }
}

// Usage
auto fooPtr = builder.build();
Foo& foo = *fooPtr;
foo.someMethod();
```

It's better, as it doesn't require manual `delete`, this two-liner conversion to reference is ugly, and, what's more important, it uses heap allocation, while simple builder-less version would be totally ok with just a simple stack allocation:

```
Foo foo(..., ...); // <= on stack
```

Are there any better ways to do that, i.e. without unique_ptr, or with some sort of on-stack allocation for Foo?

Comment: In C++, this is often called the *named parameters idiom*

Comment: Read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: *this two-liner conversion to reference is ugly,* You don't need to get the reference. Simply use `fooPtr->someMethod();`.

Comment: if `Foo` is small or easily moveable then returning by value would be more clear and flexible (but RVO might make this a moot point)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Even if it is not small, it should get RVO'd anyway.

Comment: Unrelated terminology : Raw pointers are not the problem. Raw pointers are just a ordinary pointers. The problem with `new` is in establishing "ownership".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, if Foo is [copy_constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible), then you can just return Foo by value.

```
#include <type_traits>

class Foo
{
    int i;

public:
    Foo(int i): i(i){}

};

static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<Foo>::value, "Foo is copy-constructible");

struct FooFactory
{
    //...
    Foo build() {return Foo(1);}
};


int main()
{
    FooFactory factory;
    //...
    Foo foo = factory.build();
}
```

And new in c++17, is [*guaranteed* copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), which means that you can return by value even if the type does not have copy or move constructors:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Foo
{
    int i;

public:
    Foo(int i): i(i){}
    // regular copy constructors don't exist for whatever reason. 
    Foo() = delete;
    Foo(Foo const& ) =delete;
    Foo(Foo&& ) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(Foo const&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(Foo&& ) = delete;
};

static_assert(not std::is_copy_constructible<Foo>::value, "Foo is definitely not copy-constructible");


struct FooFactory
{
    //...
    Foo build() {return Foo(1);}
};


int main()
{
    FooFactory factory;
    //...
    Foo foo = factory.build();
}
```

Comment: "*And new in c++17, is copy elision*" - copy elision is not new in C++17, it is a common optimization used by many compilers of earlier C++ versions.  What *is* new in C++17 is **guaranteed** copy elision, whereas it is **optional** in earlier versions.

Comment: Prior to C++17 the compiler must still complain if the copy constructor is not available, even if it is able to perform copy elision. Now, because of the guaranteed copy elision, the copy construtor does not need to be present.

But thank you for the correction, I've updated the post to insert that keyword.

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason why you *have* to allocate on the heap to use the builder pattern. Just have your `build()` method return `Foo` directly:

```
class FooBuilder {
public:
    Foo build() { // You may consider having a &&-qualified overload
        return Foo{ ..., ... };
    }
};
```